# How to set a time scale to a ChartJS chart from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chart.js, gantt-chart

I'm trying to code a Gantt chart using chartJS and I can't find how to do it by getting dates from json in Ajax function. Here is the code I use :

```
$.ajax({
url: "query.php",
method: "GET",
success: function(data) {
  for(var i in data) {
    field.push(data[i].c_nom);
    dates.push({x:data[i].c_min,x2:data[i].c_max, y: field[i]})
  }
console.log(dates);
}
});
```

So the logs for the line 'test4' are :

```
{x: '2022-04-06', x2: '2022-04-29', y: 'test4'}
```

And here is what I get :

[image: Result of datas]

I don't know if I can use "x2" field because chartJS doesn't take it. So the bar is
coming from 1970 I guess, and stopping at "x"...

If I put manually the dates like this -  data : [['2022-04-06','2022-04-29']] , in the data instead of my array "dates", it works...

Any point in the correct direction would be most beneficial. I will also answer any queries.

Sorry if my english is not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer by myself and it was to write the push like this :

```
dates.push({x:[data[i].c_min,data[i].c_max], y: field[i]})
```

If that may help.
Thanks if you tried to help me.